# Set and get BIOS settings using iLO

Tags: automation, bios

How can I set/get BIOS settings using iLO connection, I need to automate the configuring of BIOS setting that I do manually. It does not matter what programming/scripting language to use, and also I have a wide variety of machines vendors(IBM, HP, DELL) so let me know how to do that on any of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for HP use conrep!

description:

command-line utility for capturing/applying BIOS settings using xml definition files.

capture current settings to xml file

```
/opt/hp/conrep -s -f <filename>
```

apply settings from xml input file

```
/opt/hp/conrep -l -f <filename>
```

help

```
Usage /opt/hp/conrep -s | -l [-f output filename] [-x xml configuration filename] [-?]

-s Saves the current configuration to a file.
-l Loads configuration setting from a file.
-f Name of the output file.
-x Name of the XML definition file.  Provide the /opt/hp/conrep.xml full path.
    If not present, the XML configuration will default to conrep.xml
    If not present, the output filename default to conrep.dat
```

Error Codes:

```
0 - Success
1 - Bad XML File
2 - Bad Data File
4 - Admin Password set
5 - No XML Tag
6 - Platform is not supported with current XML definition file.
```